# ParentNode and insertBefore

Tags: javascript, child-nodes, parent-node

I created a prompt box with a question. After answering, you receive the answer in a `div` created with JavaScript called `id2`. Now I am trying to place my `id2` in front of `id1` which is the parentNode. So it will show the answer above the first div `id1`. Can someone explain to me why it's not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>lab7</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" lang="en" name="my page" />
<style>
  .class1 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: #BCC6CC;
         }  
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function loadQ() {
     var firstdiv = document.createElement("div");
         firstdiv.setAttribute("class", "class1");
         firstdiv.setAttribute("id", "id1");
     var jw = prompt("Which movie is number 1 Box Office 2015?","Jurassic World");
     document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML ="" + jw + "   Made $652,198,011 Total Gross Sales";
     document.getElementById("id2").style.backgroundColor = "#786D5F";
     var id1 = document.getElementByTagName("div")[0];
     var parent1 = id1.parentNode();
     var beforeME = document.getElementByTagName("id2");
     parent1.insertBefore(id1, beforeME);

    };
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadQ()">
   <div id="id1" class="class1">
     <br>
        <b>Top 2 Box Office Movie for 2015</b>
   </div>
   <div class="class2" id="id2">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope you pay more attention to your code than you do to your question title.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues in your code:

- `document.getElementsByTagName` needs an `s` (it returns multiple element**s**).
- To get an object by id, you need to use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Thanks I corrected the missing "s" and I changed `var beforeME = document.getElementById("id2");` however the div still stay below the parentNode

Comment: Your code gets the first div (which is the one which contains "Top 2 Box Office Movie for 2015"), then gets its parent node (which is the `body`), then inserts the new div before the div with id `id2` (which is the empty div). So it's inserted exactly where you're telling it to. If you want to insert it somewhere else, you'll have to tell us exactly where). By the way, you're creating a new div with an id `id1` when you already have one, that's not a good thing.

Comment: Thanks, you were right I was keep going in cirlce. I just figure it out today! I am going to put the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my code and made it more clear. So, each div id and class are define.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadQ() {
            var firstdiv = document.createElement("div");
                firstdiv.setAttribute("class", "class1");
                firstdiv.setAttribute("id", "id1");
                firstdiv.style.backgroundColor = "#BCC6CC;";
    document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML ="<h2 style='padding:20px;'>Top Box Office Movie 2015</h2>","<br><br>";

            var seconddiv = document.createElement("div");
                seconddiv.setAttribute("class", "class2");
                seconddiv.setAttribute("id", "id2");
                seconddiv.style.backgroundColor = "#786D5F";
                    var reper = document.getElementById('id1');
                    var parinte = reper.parentNode;
                        parinte.insertBefore(seconddiv, reper);
</script>
```